# Stata formula in R without Stata installation

Tags: r, stata, translate

Is it possible to translate a Stata formula into R without having a Stata installation on your PC?

My question is just the above, but let me give you some background how it came to me:
I have the following Stata formula

```
Mtilde=((M:/p):/d)'*M
```

(`M` is a matrix, `p` and `d` are vectors)

I want to convert it to R. I know there is the `Rstata` package, but it requires a Stata installation, which is not available on the PC I am working.

This is what I did in R:

```
Mtilde <- ((M/p)/d) %>% t() %>% `%*%`(M)
```

but it doesn't seem to work and I can not think a way to resolve it...

Comment: Could you give a simple example - maybe even a 2x2 matrix - and the expected result? Even if you had to calculate it by hand, that would help to figure out the right R code.

Comment: @thelatemail you are right, I will try to post an example, but since I will solve it literally by hand, it will take me some time...

Comment: @thelatemail, it turned that the problem was in my definition: I defined that p and d as vectors, but they should have been matrices for the formula to work properly. I realized that by solving it by hand... Thank you anyway and apologies for not being able to deliver a working example...

Comment: Good to hear. The number of times I've found a mistake in code by doing a back of the envelope calculation is too many!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is technically Mata, not Stata, code. Mata is the newer of Stata's two matrix programming languages. You invoke it by typing `mata` in the Stata command window.

Without knowing more about M and p, it is hard to give concrete advice. You can find Mata manuals online as pdf files. See the op_colon entry [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m-2op_colon.pdf#m-2op_colon) and the c_conformability entry [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/m-6glossary.pdf).

Colon operators perform element-by-element operations, so  M :/ p divides each element of M by the corresponding element of p if the two are the same size.

If they are not the same size, something similar happens (say divide by the same row or column vector), which works as long as the dimensions of the vectors is suitable.

One that is done, you calculate the transpose of that twice divided matrix, and matrix multiply by the original M.

Here are some mata examples:

```
. mata
------------------------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) ------------------------------------------------------------------
: M=(1,2\3,4)

: M
       1   2
    +---------+
  1 |  1   2  |
  2 |  3   4  |
    +---------+

: p=(1,2)

: p
       1   2
    +---------+
  1 |  1   2  |
    +---------+

: M:/p
       1   2
    +---------+
  1 |  1   1  |
  2 |  3   2  |
    +---------+

: M:/p'
         1     2
    +-------------+
  1 |    1     2  |
  2 |  1.5     2  |
    +-------------+

: ((M:/p):/p)
        1    2
    +-----------+
  1 |   1   .5  |
  2 |   3    1  |
    +-----------+

: ((M:/p):/p)'*M
         1     2
    +-------------+
  1 |   10    14  |
  2 |  3.5     5  |
    +-------------+

: end
```

Here's the corresponding R version:

```
> M <- matrix(1:4,2,2,byrow=TRUE)
> M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
> p <- matrix((1:2), 1, 2)
> p
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
> t(p)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
> # the second argument needs to be 1 for row or 2 for column
> sweep(M, 2, p, FUN = '/') 
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    3    2
> sweep(M, 1, t(p), FUN = '/')
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0    2
[2,]  1.5    2
> sweep(sweep(M, 2, p, FUN = '/'),2,p,FUN = '/')
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  0.5
[2,]    3  1.0
> t(sweep(sweep(M, 2, p, FUN = '/'),2,p,FUN = '/'))%*%M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 10.0   14
[2,]  3.5    5
```

Comment: Thanx @Dimitriy, it is actually mata code like you said. The problem was (like you pointed out) that the dimensions of the vector were convenient to make the division, but it turned out that they should have been matrices for the formula to work properly! Thank for the comprehensive reply!